# Trying to understand utility of Cox vs. logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, survival, cox-model

I am refreshing myself on the different types of regression models and am getting a little stuck between logistic regression and Cox regression/survival analysis. Here's an example: Let's say you are evaluating an intervention. You have two groups - an intervention group and a control group. You have follow-up data on everyone through the 1-yr mark and you want to compare fatality risk between the groups. Is it more appropriate to do survival analysis so that you can factor in different the different lengths of person-time or is it more appropriate to just do logistic regression (yes/no person is alive at the 1-year mark)? It seems like the benefit of survival analysis is that it allows you to factor in censoring and that many people who are alive at the 1-yr mark may die after you've finished following-up. But in this case, if the question is specific to each group's fatality risk within 1-yr... does factoring in censoring matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is not really statistical -- you have stated the difference. Logistic is about dichotomous responses (unless you do multinomial or ordinal logistic). Survival is about time to event.

If you are *only* interested in 1 year mortality, then logistic is fine. But then you ask "does it matter?"  And ... well, I'm guessing it matters to the patients!

I mean, maybe your  research question is just about that specific time period. But why? Also, while it is very dangerous to extrapolate, the survival curve might give *some* indication about how much longer the survivors will live. It will surely give some indication of when the ones who die are dying. If a lot of people are dying in the first month, then it slows, that's a lot different than a constant rate.

Also, you sort of hint at left censoring (people starting at different times), so, to get to 1 year for everyone, you'd have to wait until 1 year after the last person started. Survival analysis can help with that.

OTOH, to me, logistic is a little easier to understand.

So, TLDR, I think this is more a question of what you want to know, rather than which method is right.

Comment: Sorry - I can see that my question wasn't very clear. In this scenario, your study is 1-yr long, so you have data on everyone through that point. So if the research question is: "does the intervention group have a lower fatality risk at 1-year?", which method is "better"? From the sound of your response, it sounds like logistic can be employed (and I agree that it's more easily understood), but the benefit of survival analysis is that you can see how that risk changes within your follow-up period?

Comment: OK, if everyone started at the same time, there's no left censoring. 

But, otherwise, yes, that's what I am saying. You might want to plot the survival curves and then decide which method to use.